# Second angular button not calling function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

small issue and I'm probably being really dumb, but I have 2 buttons for a webpage which should contact a server. However only the first one sends a HTTP request when it's pressed.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('buttonApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.myFunc = function(url) {
           console.log("func called");
           $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: url,
           }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
           }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("Failed connection");
           });
       }
   });
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="buttonApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myFunc('/buttonPressed1')">b1</button>
</div>

<div ng-app="buttonApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myFunc('/buttonPressed2')">b2</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the server code.

```
var express = require('express');                   
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
var button = true;

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.testing = 'device-protocol';
  return next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){                                 
  console.log('get route', req.testing);
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "button.htm" );
});

app.post('/buttonPressed1', function(req, res){
  //do some stuff
  console.log("Button 1 pressed");
  res.send("success");
});

app.post('/buttonPressed2', function(req, res){
  //do some stuff
  console.log("Button 2 pressed");
  res.send("success");
});
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Test server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)**, Angular app cannot have  two **`ng-app`** and **`ng-controller`**, Have one module and controller like below,

```
<body ng-app="buttonApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div >
    <button ng-click="myFunc('/buttonPressed1')">b1</button>
</div>    
<div>
    <button ng-click="myFunc('/buttonPressed2')">b2</button>
</div>
</body>
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('buttonApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.myFunc = function(url) {
           console.log("func called"+url);
           
       }
   });
</script>
<body  ng-app="buttonApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
    <button ng-click="myFunc('/buttonPressed1')">b1</button>
</div>

<div ng-app="buttonApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myFunc('/buttonPressed2')">b2</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not just **don't need**,  it's **cannot have**.  Angular does not allow two copies of `ng-app`, ever.

Comment: @Claies thats the same thing i have mentioned

Comment: you said "don't need", which isn't the same as "can't have".  I am suggesting it could be a little more clear that its not even possible at all.

Comment: glad to help :)